# How can i make this custom text search field in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I want this search bar.

Expected : -
[image: Expected]

I tried the below code but it's not working as expected.

Achieved: - [image]

```
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBy,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
                .width(width = 277.dp)
                .height(height = 38.dp)
                .padding(end = 12.dp)
        ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.elogo),
            contentDescription = "e logo",
            modifier = Modifier
                        .size(size = 46.dp))
        TextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {})
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.vector),
            contentDescription = "Vector",
            alpha = 0.5f,
            modifier = Modifier
                        .width(width = 19.dp)
                        .height(height = 19.dp))
        }
```

I need circled corners along with the two logos at both the ends.

Comment: Ia the image what you want or what you tried to achieve? Please post images of what you have tried and what you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this , first create custom search view

```
    @Composable
    fun CustomSearchView(
        search: String,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
    ) {
    
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(20.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(Color(0XFF101921))
    
        ) {
            TextField(value = search,
                onValueChange = onValueChange,
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color(0XFF101921),
                    placeholderColor = Color(0XFF888D91),
                    leadingIconColor = Color(0XFF888D91),
                    trailingIconColor = Color(0XFF888D91),
                    textColor = Color.White,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent, cursorColor = Color(0XFF070E14)
                ),
                leadingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = "") },
                trailingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = "") },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Search") }
            )
        }
    
    }
```

Now use where ever you want like this ...

```
@Composable
fun Demo() {
    var search by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0XFF070E14))
    ) {
        CustomSearchView(search = search, onValueChange = {
            search = it
        })
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
val (value, onValueChange) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 17.sp),
    leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, null, tint = Color.Gray) },
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .background(Color(0xFFE7F1F1), RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
    placeholder = { Text(text = "Bun") },
    trailingIcon = {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Search,
            null,
            tint = Color.Gray,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { /*Click Action*/ })
    },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        cursorColor = Color.DarkGray
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The TextField composable has several properties which you can use (so there is no need to create a custom layout like you did):

- LeadingIcon
- TrailingIcon
- Shape (for rounded corners)

An example would look like this:

```
              Row {
                    TextField(
                        value = text,
                        onValueChange = {  },
                        leadingIcon = Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.elogo),
                            contentDescription = "Leading",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(size = 46.dp)
                        ),
                        trailingIcon = Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.vector),
                            contentDescription = "Trailing",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(width = 19.dp)
                                .height(height = 19.dp)
                                .alpha(0.5f)),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                    )
                }
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#enter-modify-text).